# Why do moderators sometimes comment on questions without closing them?

Tags: discussion

I notice that often questions that are eventually closed because enough people have flagged them, have comments from a moderator.

Why do moderators not close such questions instead?

Comment: Define "often."   I looked through the [last 50 closed questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a1) which is about three months worth.  I can only find what you describe happening  [once](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133833/i-need-help-in-linking-my-expandcart-stores-sitemap-to-google-search-console) in that time period.  I found three other instances in which a moderator made comments and the same moderator later closed the question after further discussion.

Comment: Now that I've commented here, I realize that it would be ironic if others voted to close this meta question.   ;)

Comment: OK...sometimes ;o)  It wasn't the same moderator, sorry for that confusion.  It is no drama, just something I have noticed _once in a while_ ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm doubtful that this happens all that often.   From the data I looked at, it might happen every month or two at the most.

I can't speak for all the moderators, but there are several reasons that I might comment on a question that later gets closed rather than close it myself right away:

- Not all questions are clearly off-topic.  The process of closing questions is subjective.  I might think that a question would be on-topic while other users might later vote to close it.
- When questions are borderline off-topic, moderators are encouraged to let the community decide if the question gets closed.   Moderators are supposed to be the exception-handlers for when user-led processes don't work properly.   Question closure is supposed to be handled primarily through the votes of non-moderators.  Unfortunately, Pro Webmasters doesn't have a large enough user base for this process to work well.  Moderators need to get involved in nearly all close and re-open decisions.
- In the case when a question should be closed as "Needs details or clarity," I often write a comment asking for details and leave the question open for a couple hours.   If the person who asked provides more details during that time, the question doesn't have to go through the whole close and re-open process.  To me, that seems more user friendly and less likely make our site seem unwelcoming.
- I don't always read every question carefully.  I may skim it and find something to comment without digging in enough to see that the question should be closed.
- When I am on a mobile device I often find it difficult to deal with question closing.  I find the search for duplicate questions especially hard on mobile.  When I'm using our site on my phone I may comment now and wait until I'm back at my desktop to deal with question closure.  I've also sometimes flagged questions for other moderators to deal with when I'm roaming.